# Sum up student credit hours for sets of 4 months

Tags: casting, sum, case

I need to create a report to get student credit hours based on sets of months.
Simplistic representation of the data

student   term             credit-hours   other-stuff
0000000   0000000*23MAR*UG  9              stuff1
0000001   0000001*23APR*UG  12             stuff2
0000002   0000002*23NOV*UG  11             stuff3
0000003   0000003*23DEC*UG  10             stuff4

So, in the report, 23MAR and 23APR would be term1, 23NOV and 23DEC would be term2
I need to sum up the credit hours per those sets of terms
(The report used to be are there credit hours for this term? Y/N)
Here is the case statement I used for the y/n script

Case
when [term] like ('%23MAR*UG%')
or [term] like ('%23APR*UG%')
then '1' else '0' end as term1

Case
when [term] like ('%23NOV*UG%')
or [term] like ('%23DEC*UG%')
then '1' else '0' end as term2

I used SQL many years ago, so I'm having to relearn everything

Thanks!

I tried using
when [term] like ...
cast(credit_hours as int)
else '000'
end as term1

It errors out every time